# Airflow:Date not rendering in SQL file

Tags: airflow

**Issue**: Date not rendering in SQL file

I am not able to get the date `yesterday_ds`  rendered  in the SQL file

In bi_utils/airflow.py module I have given as `YESTERDAY_DS = '{{yesterday_ds}}'`

In the Dag

```
from bi_utils.airflow import YESTERDAY_DS

snflk_to_s3 = SnowflakeMultiSqlStatmentOperator(
            task_id='snflk_to_s3',
            snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID,
            sql=load_sql,
            params={
                'proc_run_task_id': [proc_start.task_id],
                'yesterday_ds': YESTERDAY_DS,
            },
            autocommit=True,
        )
```

In the SQL file

```
COPY INTO @public.stage/path/{{params.yesterday_ds}}/
```

Comment: How about if you simply try `COPY INTO @public.stage/path/{{yesterday_ds}}/` (without the `prams.` prefix (and also need not pass `yesterday_ds` as `params`)? Since `{{yesterday_ds}}` is a valid [macro](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros-ref.html) and `SnowflakeOperator` [marks `sql` as `templated_field`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/snowflake_operator.html), this should work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a custom operator. In that case, you will have to add the argument as a **template_fields** to resolve the jinja template.

In this case, inside your custom operator, the Code below is just to understand the structure.

```
class SnowflakeMultiSqlStatmentOperator(BaseOperator):
    """
    Executes sql code in a Snowflake database
    """
    template_fields = ('sql','params')
    template_ext = ('.sql',)
    ui_color = '#ededed'

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
            self, sql, snowflake_conn_id='snowflake_default', parameters=None,
            autocommit=True, warehouse=None, database=None, role=None,
            schema=None,params=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SnowflakeOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.snowflake_conn_id = snowflake_conn_id
        self.sql = sql
        self.autocommit = autocommit
        self.parameters = parameters
        self.warehouse = warehouse
        self.database = database
        self.role = role
        self.schema = schema
        self.params=params


    def execute(self, context):
        self.log.info('Executing: %s', self.sql)
        hook = self.get_hook()
        hook.run(
            self.sql,
            autocommit=self.autocommit,
            parameters=self.parameters)
```

Comment: SnowflakeMultiSqlStatmentOperator is extending SnowflakeOperator which itself has template_fields

Comment: just add template_fields = ('sql','params') to your extended class.

Comment: SnowflakeOperator inherits from BaseOperator.
One of the input parameters of BaseOperator is params: 
   `self.params = params or {}  # Available in templates!`

Below is my Class 

`class SnowflakeMultiSqlStatmentOperator(SnowflakeOperator):
    def get_hook(self):
        return SnowflakeCustomHook(
            snowflake_conn_id=self.snowflake_conn_id,
            warehouse=self.warehouse,
            database=self.database,
        )`

Comment: If you are trying to pass your variables as parameters into the snowflake hook. It won't work because the parameters field is not templated. So you will have to explicitly specify that as template_fields in your extended class. I don't think params in the base operator has to do anything with snowflake operations.

Comment: Yes I have tried having `template_fields = ('sql','params') ` in the `class SnowflakeMultiSqlStatmentOperator(SnowflakeOperator)`

Comment: could you change the params to a different variable name as the base operator has the same variable